# Change button background by filling it left to right

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to change the background of a button while being pressed by filling it a color from left to right just like a horizontal progress bar.

This is the code for detecting press-hold:

```
lateinit var buttonView: View
val cdt = object : CountDownTimer(1000, 100) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {

            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                //do something after being press by 1 sec.
            }
        }

        val onTouchListener = View.OnTouchListener { v, event ->
            buttonView = v
            when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    (v.background as AnimationDrawable).start()
                    cdt.start()
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    (v.background as AnimationDrawable).stop()
                    cdt.cancel()
                }

            }
            false
        }
```

This is the background I used for the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...items with drawables which colors are in different position. Frame by frame....
</animation-list>
```

This works but it ain't smooth. Is there a way to do this efficiently? Just like this? https://codepen.io/kay8/pen/azKbjN
(It's okay to answer in Java)

Comment: so you want this animation on button click or just when layout appear in screen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

***Update:*** The following will not work if the button is a Material button, so make sure that your button is either a framework button (*android.widget.Button*) or an AppCompat button (*androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton*).

---

---

For the drawable, I would go with a [`ClipDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable) as the top layer in a [`LayerDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable). This will visually work like a progress bar.

In the following drawable, the clip drawable overlays a bottom layer that is just a red rectangle.

**button_background.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/clip_drawable">
        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="start">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The black of the clip drawable will eclipse the red rectangle as the level of the clip drawable increases from 0 (not shown) to 10,000 (100% covering the red rectangle.)

[`TimeAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TimeAnimator) can be used to animate the level of the clip drawable.

> This class provides a simple callback mechanism to listeners that is synchronized with all other animators in the system.

Here is a quick demo. You can change `onTimeUpdate()` to be sensitive to total and elapsed time if you want to set the duration of the animation.

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimeAnimator.TimeListener {
    private TimeAnimator mAnimator;
    private int mCurrentLevel = 0;
    private ClipDrawable mClipDrawable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get a handle on the ClipDrawable that we will animate.
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) findViewById(R.id.button).getBackground();
        mClipDrawable = (ClipDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.clip_drawable);

        // Set up TimeAnimator to fire off on button click.
        mAnimator = new TimeAnimator();
        mAnimator.setTimeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimator animation, long totalTime, long deltaTime) {
        mClipDrawable.setLevel(mCurrentLevel);
        if (mCurrentLevel >= MAX_LEVEL) {
            mAnimator.cancel();
        } else {
            mCurrentLevel = Math.min(MAX_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel + LEVEL_INCREMENT);
        }
    }

    public void animateButton(View view) {
        if (!mAnimator.isRunning()) {
            mCurrentLevel = 0;
            mAnimator.start();
        }
    }

    private static final int LEVEL_INCREMENT = 400;
    private static final int MAX_LEVEL = 10000;
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="animateButton"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```