# Button Animation (TimeAnimator with ClipDrawable) doesn't work properly

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, android-animation

I want to animate button background by filling it left to right. I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239290/10897068) . It works properly, when I put it in `onCreate`but I need to animate button when user select the correct answer in my quize.
Here is my checkAnswer method

```
fun checkAnswer(selectedAnswer: Button) {
        enableAnswersButton(false)
        if (selectedAnswer.text.toString() == listOfTests[currentQuestion].rightAnswer){
            val layerDrawable = selectedAnswer.background as LayerDrawable
            mClipDrawable =
                layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.clip_drawable_false) as ClipDrawable

            mAnimator = TimeAnimator()
            mAnimator!!.setTimeListener(this)

            selectedAnswer.setOnClickListener {

                if (!mAnimator!!.isRunning) {
                    mCurrentLevel = 0;
                    mAnimator!!.start()
                }
            }
        } else {
            val layerDrawable = selectedAnswer.background as LayerDrawable
            mClipDrawable =
                layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.clip_drawable_true) as ClipDrawable

            mAnimator = TimeAnimator()
            mAnimator!!.setTimeListener(this)


            selectedAnswer.setOnClickListener {

                if (!mAnimator!!.isRunning) {
                    mCurrentLevel = 0;
                    mAnimator!!.start()
                }
            }
```

The problem is the animation works from time to time. Sometimes `onTimeUpdate` method doesn't called and animations doesn't work.

```
  override fun onTimeUpdate(animation: TimeAnimator?, totalTime: Long, deltaTime: Long) {
        mClipDrawable!!.level = mCurrentLevel
        if (mCurrentLevel >= MAX_LEVEL) {
            mAnimator!!.cancel()
        } else {
            mCurrentLevel = min(MAX_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel + LEVEL_INCREMENT)
        }

    }
```

Please, help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54147277/change-button-background-by-filling-it-left-to-right/54239290#54239290)!. the implementation there is fine, only you should not use

```
  selectedAnswer.setOnClickListener {//<===this part need to be removed as its setting onClick which will work if next time same button is clicked 

            if (!mAnimator!!.isRunning) {
                mCurrentLevel = 0;
                mAnimator!!.start()
            }
        }
```

the part need to be removed as its setting onClick which will work if next time same button is click

if you want to play animation only when any answer button is pressed. you need to **set animator at the time of setting options on answer text views/buttons**

Below Code can give you an Idea

```
   firstOptionTextView.setText(Put the Option here);

   if (firstOptionTextView.text.toString() == listOfTests[currentQuestion].rightAnswer){
        val layerDrawable = selectedAnswer.background as LayerDrawable
        mClipDrawable =
            layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.clip_drawable_false) as ClipDrawable

        mAnimator = TimeAnimator()
        mAnimator!!.setTimeListener(this)

        firstOptionTextView.setOnClickListener {

            if (!mAnimator!!.isRunning) {
                mCurrentLevel = 0;
                mAnimator!!.start()
            }
        }
    } else {
        val layerDrawable = selectedAnswer.background as LayerDrawable
        mClipDrawable =
            layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.clip_drawable_true) as ClipDrawable

        mAnimator = TimeAnimator()
        mAnimator!!.setTimeListener(this)


        firstOptionTextView.setOnClickListener {

            if (!mAnimator!!.isRunning) {
                mCurrentLevel = 0;
                mAnimator!!.start()
            }
        }
```

now since this option has an animator either for correct tor incorrect it will be played.

Comment: To do so you need to save another animator separately  to the  **correct answer**, once **any button is clicked and its animator** is started, manually start **Correct button's ** animator